# AttributeError: 'FigureCanvasWxAgg' object has no attribute '_idletimer'

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, wxpython

I am creating a GUI program using wxPython.  I am also using matplotlib to graph some data.  This data needs to be animated. To animate the data I am using the FuncAnimate function, which is part of the matplotlib package.

When I first started to write my code I was using a PC, running windows 7.  I did my initial testing on this computer and everything was working fine.  However my program needs to be cross platform.  So I began to run some test using a Mac.  This is where I began to encounter an error.  As I explained before, in my code I have to animate some data.  I programmed it such that the user has the ability to play and pause the animation.  Now when the user pauses the animation I get the following error: AttributeError: 'FigureCanvasWxAgg' object has no attribute '_idletimer'.  Now I find this to be very strange because like I said I ran this same code on a PC and never got this error.

I was wondering if anyone could explain to me what is meant by this _idletimer error and what are possible causes for this.

Answer (score 1):

`_idletimer` is likely to be a private, possibly implementation specific member of one of the classes - since you do not include the code or context I can not tell you which.

In general anything that starts with an `_` is private and if it is not **your own**, and specific to the local class, should not be used by your code as it may change or even disappear when you rely on it.

Comment: I was just wondering why this error only occurs on the Mac OS and not the PC. On the PC, I am using pythonxy and on the Mac I am using the enthought distribution of python.

Comment: Because there is a different installation of python with different copies of the libraries running on a different OS!  Even the same versions of the external modules _may_ use different private variables and functions on different OSs and different versions even more so - that is the nature of private members they are there for the convenience of the package developer __not__ the user so _can not be relied on_.